# Error in checking if pointer reaches end-of-string

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am working on a string reversal problem where I am trying to swap values from two ends with one another. As a part of the reverse function, I have a line that checks whether the pointer has reached the end-of-string character (in the form of `while(*end!= '\0')`). However, this doesn't seem to be working, and at the end of the while loop when I de-reference "end" I get blank. When I use (`while(*end)`), everything works perfectly but I have to then decrement my pointer "end" to make sure I am accessing the last element of my string. Why can't I check the pointer against the string literal '\0'?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void reverse(char* s);

void main(){
    char str[]="abcdef";
    printf("%s\n",str);
    reverse(str);
    printf("%s\n",str);
}

void reverse(char* p){  
    char* start = p;
    char* end = p;
    char tmp;
    int length =0;

    while(*end!='\0'){
        end+=1;
        length+=1;
    }
    printf("%c\n",*end); // problem line

    int c;
    for (c = 0; c < length/2; c++)
    {        
      tmp   = *start;
      *start   = *end;
      *end = tmp;

      start++;
      end--;
    }
    //printf("%s\n",p);
}
```

Comment: At the "problem line" `*end` equals `\0`, i.e. `end` points to the end-of-string character. With both `while(*end!='\0')` end  `while(*end)` you should end up in this end-of-string character. So you should decrement `end` before beginning the reversion. Maybe I missed a point in your question.

Comment: D'oh, of course. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In the `//Problem line` the value of `*end` is `'\0'` - You should print the integer value of `'\0'` to verify which is **0** & it works - apart from that you'll need to uncomment the `}` from `reverse` function.

`'\0'` is a non printable character: [Reference: Non-printable and Printable ASCII Characters](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/idp5.1/topics/reference/general/intrusion-detection-prevention-custom-attack-object-extended-ascii.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t mystrlen(const char *str)
{
    const char *ptr = str;

    while(*ptr++);

    return ptr - str;
}

char *reverse(char *str)
{
    size_t len = mystrlen(str);
    char *end = str + len -1;
    char *saved = str;

    len /= 2;
    while(len--)
    {
        char tmp = *str;
        *str++ = *end;
        *end-- = tmp;
    }
    return saved;
}

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "This is the string which will be reversed";

    printf("%s\n", reverse(str));

}
```

Comment: Why not use `*--end = tmp;` and not have that other `-1` at the top?

Comment: @AlexisWilke because importancy of it is marginal (as thew most time is consumed in the loop) and I wanted to show OP where his error is.

Comment: One thing I like, though, is you breaking up the code in separate reusable functions. This is good.

Answer (score 0):

your code works. end reaches '\0'. but printf prints string until the first '\0'. so your print appears empty. if you add after the while loop:
--end;
or change the while to:  while(*(end+1))
your code will do what you want it to

Comment: `while(*(end+1))` is wrong. If the string is empty, it will miss the `'\0'`. The `--end` after the loop is okay. If the string is empty his `for()` does nothing anyway. However, moving the `--end;` in the `for()` loop is a better idea.

Comment: good point, there should be a check to make sure that it is not an empty string. And always a check that pointer is not NULL if it is  dereferenced, so, it is good practice to check (p!= NULL) at the beginning of he function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `length` variable, and you can use pre-decrement on `end`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse(char *start);

int main(void) {
    char str[]= "abcdef";
    printf("%s\n", str);
    reverse(str);
    printf("%s\n", str);
}

void reverse(char* start) {
    char *end = start;
    while(*end != '\0') {
        end++;
    }
    while(start < end) {
        char temp = *--end;
        *end = *start;
        *start++ = temp;
    }
}
```